# Algorithm to find subsets with high correlation

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, correlation, dimensionality-reduction

I have a reasonably large dataset (d) with predictor variables x1...xn and a target variable y. I can use recursive partitioning (such as CART or rpart in R) to find subsets of d with a high (or low) average y. However, I am interested in subsets with a high **correlation** between x1 and y. For example, suppose that in the subset defined by d[x2>5 & x3<7], the linear model y = a*x1 + b has an r^2 of 90%, which I will call 'high.' I am looking for an algorithm that will take in dataset d, find the subset d[x2>5 & x3<7] (as well as others that would produce a high r^2 using the linear model), and give me, as output, the list of subsets found and the r^2 of each. Just like in recursive partitioning, this algo would look for subsets as large as possible, and try to arrive at them using as few 'steps' or 'cuts' as possible (e.g. d[x2>5 & x3<7] would be two 'cuts')

In an ideal world, I would even get to specify the model - i.e. instead of using a linear model y = a*x1 + b, I would like to use a logistic model, since y is binary in my particular dataset.

Is there an algorithm that can find those subsets for me automatically? Is this algorithm perchance implemented in R?

Thank you!

Comment: There is one solution, but only under the following two conditions: a) all the variables involved (including the response) are continuous, and, b) the size of the subset you are looking for is $>n/2$ where $n$ is the size of your data set.

Comment: To obtain useful results, you will need to add more constraints to this question, because *any* subset of $2$ elements having different values of $x_1$ and $y$ will exhibit perfect correlation ($R^2=1$) with $y$.

Comment: That's like saying recursive partitioning isn't useful because you could just find the maximum value of y and end the search... Clearly, we are looking for subsets with as many observations as possible while meeting some threshold r^2.

Comment: Because that is not in the least clear, it would be good if you would edit your question to include that criterion.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear a two-observations subset is not the solution, but I've made the edit nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might find something of interest using the caret package:
The method findCorrelation does what you want.
You can change the value to the desired amount.

```
library(caret) 
tooHigh <- findCorrelation(cor(rbind(Xtrain,Xtest)), .95) 
Xtrainfiltered <- Xtrain[, -tooHigh]
Xtestfiltered  <-  Xtest[, -tooHigh]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, this appears to look for pairs of variables (columns, x1..xn in my example) that are highly correlated. I am looking for a subset (rows) in which x1 and y are highly correlated.